# how to select a range of rows conditioned to start and end given certain text

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that its format looks like this. I want to clean the df leaving a certain range of rows that starts when column 1 says "country" and ends two rows before it says "end" in column 1. I need it that way because later I have to bind the df with others dfs of the same type of sheet but from other periods, so the range differs between sheets.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| - | - | - |
| country | number | year |
| china | 1 | 2018 |
| japan | 2 | 2019 |
| usa | 3 | 2019 |
|  |  |  |
| end |  |  |

| country | number | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| china | 1 | 2018 |
| japan | 2 | 2019 |
| usa | 3 | 2019 |

I want it to look like this but it hasn't worked with the code I've been trying to use:

```
  start_position <- which(df[,1]=="country")
  end_position <- which(df[,1]=="end")
  df<- df[df(start_position:(end_position-2)),]
```

Any help or recommendations pleasee

Answer (score 0):

```
start_position <- which(df[,1]=="country")
end_position <- which(df[,1]=="end")
# change the third line
#         ___                               _       
# df<- df[df(start_position:(end_position-2)),]
#
df <- df[ start_position:(end_position-2),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
library(tibble)
df <- tribble(
  ~ColumnA, ~ColumnB, ~ColumnC,
  "-", "-", "-",
  "country", "number", "year",
  "china", "1", "2018",
  "japan", "2", "2019",
  "usa", "3", "2019",
  "end", "", ""
)

names_idx <- which(df[, 1] == "country")
end_idx <- which(df[, 1] == "end")

out <- df[(names_idx + 1):(end_idx - 1), ]
colnames(out) <- as.vector(as.matrix(df)[names_idx, ])
out
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  country number year 
  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>
1 china   1      2018 
2 japan   2      2019 
3 usa     3      2019
```